# Pandas Python - Create subplots from 2 CSV columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to create subplots: first Pie plot (got it), second bar plot (didn't succeed):

These are the columns:

[image: data screenshot]

My Code:

```
top_series = all_data.head(50).groupby('Top Rated ')['Top Rated '].count()
top_values = top_series.values.tolist()
top_index = ['Top Rated', 'Not Top Rated']
top_colors = ['#27AE60', '#E74C3C']

all_data['Rating_Cat'] = all_data['Rating'].apply(lambda x : 'High' if (x > 10000000 ) else 'Low')

rating_series = all_data.head(50).groupby('Rating_Cat')['Rating_Cat'].count()
rating_values = rating_series.values.tolist()
rating_index = ['High' , 'Low']
rating_colors = ['#F1C40F', '#27AE60']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(16,5))
axs[0].pie(top_values, labels=top_index, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
           explode=(0.05, 0.05), radius=1.2, colors=top_colors, textprops={'fontsize':12})

all_data['Rating_Cat'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', ax=axs[1])
fig.suptitle('Does "Rating" really affect on Top Sellers ?' , fontsize=17)
```

My question:
How to create the second plot that will get output like:

axis X = 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 .... 50 + Top reated / NO (according to the current col)
axis y = the rating from 0 to 7603388.0

I have really tried lots of things, but I am kind of lost here... please help !!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, so I'll try to reiterate the problem:
- You have 2 columns. `Rating` and `Top rated`. You want to have each of the values from `Rating` plotted from first to last with color based on the `Top rated`?

Comment: @DanielWlazło
Yes! but just the 100first rows.. how can i make it ?

Comment: Hi OmerB, do you mind providing a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

In first plot you are taking first 50 rows of the dataset and plot shares of each value in `Top Rated`  column.

If I understand what you are trying to do in second plot (You want to have each of the `Rating` from first 100 values plotted from first to last with color based on the Top rated):

```
#taking first 100 rows
rating_series = all_data.head(100).copy()
#assigning color to the values, so you could use it in bar() plot
rating_series["color"] = rating_series["Top Rated "].map({"Top Rated": "#27AE60", "No": "#E74C3C"})
#plotting the values
axs[1].bar(rating_series.index, rating_series["Rating"], color = rating_series["color"])
```

If you want to add legend to the plot, you have to do it manually

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
axs[1].legend(handles=[mpatches.Patch(color='#27AE60', label='Top Rated'),
               mpatches.Patch(color='#E74C3C', label='Not Top Rated')])
```

Edit: My whole code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import random
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Rating": np.random.randint(0,7603388,size=200),
        "Top Rated ": [random.choice(['Top Rated', 'No']) for rated in range(0,200)]
    }
)

#taking first 100 rows
rating_series = df.head(100).copy()
#assigning color to the values, so you could use it in bar() plot
rating_series["color"] = rating_series["Top Rated "].map({"Top Rated": "#27AE60", "No": "#E74C3C"})
#checking if there were no NaNs
rating_series["color"].value_counts(dropna=False)

#Output:

#E74C3C    53
#FFC300    47
#Name: color, dtype: int64

#1st plot
top_series = rating_series.groupby('Top Rated ')['Top Rated '].count()
top_index = ['Top Rated', 'Not Top Rated']
top_colors = ['#27AE60', '#E74C3C']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(16,5))
axs[0].pie(top_series.values, labels=top_index, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
           explode=(0.05, 0.05), radius=1.2, colors=top_colors, textprops={'fontsize':12})

#2nd plot
axs[1].bar(rating_series.index, rating_series["Rating"], color = rating_series["color"])
axs[1].legend(handles=[mpatches.Patch(color='#27AE60', label='Top Rated'),
               mpatches.Patch(color='#E74C3C', label='Not Top Rated')])
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks you so much ! how i can handle the `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: nan ` whats wront with the length of the RGBA ?

Comment: Each element in the `rating_series["color"]` (or other iterable used in the color argument of the bar function) must have only colour values. You can f.e. check it by doing `value_counts(dropna=False)`

Comment: ?
`#plotting the values
rating_series.value_counts(dronpa=False)
axs[1].bar(rating_series.index, rating_series["Rating"], color = rating_series["color"])`

Comment: I uploaded my whole code. As you can see, when doing `rating_series["color"].value_counts(dropna=False)` there should be no NaNs in output (only the colour codes). 
If there are NaNs, that mean, that the values in the `"Top Rated "` column are different  than the `"Top Rated"` and `"No"`  (maybe some whitespaces or something), and should be updated in the `map` method.


I uploaded my entire code, I hope it would help you, because I'm done with this question.

Comment: omg god bless you man !